# GCP Pub/Sub: Acknowledgement deadline doesn't work when reading messages

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

Creating a subscription on GCP Pub Sub with "Acknowledgement deadline" set as its max value (600 seconds), my java client in spring boot, keeps receiving messages every 60 seconds in case the task is still running.

[pub/sub subscription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2thc.png)

We have a simple consumer very similar to this:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-gcp-pubsub/

We need to perform operations which can run for some minutes each, but even setting 600 seconds, if the task hasn't finished after 60 seconds, the message arrives again.

Doesn't someone experienced something similar?
Thanks

**Update:**

These are the main dependencies:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.10.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<spring-cloud-gcp.version>1.2.6.RELEASE</spring-cloud-gcp.version>

<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And this is the setup in the consumer (it's exactly as the spring boot guide linked above explains):

```
@Bean
public PubSubInboundChannelAdapter messageChannelAdapter(
        @Qualifier("pubsubInputChannel") MessageChannel inputChannel,
        PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate) {
    LOGGER.info("pubsubInputChannel");
    PubSubInboundChannelAdapter adapter =
            new PubSubInboundChannelAdapter(pubSubTemplate, subscription);
    adapter.setOutputChannel(inputChannel);
    adapter.setAckMode(AckMode.AUTO_ACK);
    return adapter;
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel pubsubInputChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "pubsubInputChannel")
public MessageHandler messageReceiver() {
    return message -> {
        String json = new String((byte[]) message.getPayload());
        LOGGER.info("Message arrived! Payload: " + json);
        //Main code here
        //Operations might take some minutes to be finished
    };
}
```

Comment: Where do you consume the messages? On your local environment?

Comment: Yes I do, but we do have the same issue with the deployed version in Kubernetes Engine

Comment: Can you share a minimal reproductible code?

Comment: Just added an update

Comment: Based on your settings, I'm surprised this is happening. Your usage of Spring looks good. As long as your code is not throwing RuntimeExceptions, your message will be acked after the message reception method works.

1) Are you sure your code is sending an Ack after running your per-message logic?

2) How consistently do you get the messages redelivered? Every time or just once in a while?

Comment: 1) I don't know how to double check it, but having it set as "AckMode.AUTO_ACK" I do expect that happens already automatically. 2) It happens for every message. I do get a runtime exception: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED after 59.4672346732s

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing using the C++ client library. I have a subscription with Acknowledgement deadline set to 600s, but the unacknowledged messages are redelivered every 60s.